# Are RAID volumes compatible between OSes?

Tags: raid

I have a RAID 1 (mirrored) volume made of 2 USB external drives which was created on macOS High Sierra and I wanted to check if I can plug these drives into another machine running an earlier version of macOS like Sierra.

Are RAID volumes independent of the Mac OS that created them?

Comment: AppleRAID has been the same since I can remember so they should be backward compatible.  However, I have hardly (if ever) used software based RAID that I couldn't tell you how to migrate from one machine to another.  Your best bet is to give it a try.  Make sure your data is backed up.